# Is there any way to deploy JavaFX as web application using Spring?

Tags: spring, javafx

I managed to deploy JavaFX as web application using JPro and was also able to reach integration of Spring and JavaFX using FxWeaver, however I haven't found anything regarding deploying JavaFX as web application using Spring. Is this possible and is the question posed correctly at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, [JPro](https://www.jpro.one/) is using [Play](https://www.playframework.com/) as a web framework.
This is only an implementation detail, which doesn't affect the developer, which allows us to switch the web framework without causing any issues.

We plan to use Spring in an upcoming release.

Then we will support adding JavaFX with JPro to an existing Spring application.
We will also support using Spring from a different classloader, to avoid conflicts in the dependencies between Spring and the JavaFX application, which is exactly what we currently do with the Play Framework.